# completing the square with a coefficient more than 1.

Tags: completing-the-square

I've tried to solve it, is this right?

$$2x^2+6x+35=0$$

$$2(x^2+6x)+35$$

$$2(x+3)^2+35-9=0$$

$$2(x+3)^2=26=0$$

I was told to write it in the form $a(x+b)^2+c$.

Comment: $$35-2\cdot3^2=?$$

Comment: No, $2x^2+6x\neq 2(x^2+6x)$.

Comment: oh crap i just saw that. did i do the rest of the method correctly?

Comment: I redid it and got this.   2(x+3/2)^2-32.75=0

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error saying $2x^2+6x=2(x^2+6x)$, the second line loses the $=0$ at the end, the $-9$ came from inside parentheses multiplied by $2$ so should be $-18$, and the equals sign before the $26$ in the last line should be a plus sign.  Finally, the form you are given is an expression while you are working with an equation.

Answer (score 0):

$2x^2+6x+35=2(x^2+3x)+35=2(x+\frac{3}{2})^2+(\frac{61}{2})$

This is what I did to obtain the constant term $\frac{61}{2}$:

Let $d$ be the constant term then $2(\frac{3}{2})^2+d=35 \rightarrow d=35-\frac{9}{2}=\frac{61}{2}$.

Comment: So you are doing 1.5^2 then multiplying it by two? So its 2.25x2 =4.5     =35-4.5-30.5 =61/2

Comment: @LiamMichel Yes.